# regex for USA phone number format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am using [1000hz](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) for validation.
for +1(999) 999-999 phone number I am using this regex in pattern

```
^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$
```

but its not working.

Comment: This regex only accepts `+(999) 999-999`

Comment: ... also be aware that one needs to provide the pattern-string in a way that it can be consumed by JavaScript's `RegExp` function/constructor. Thus some regex specific characters might need to be escaped additionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match a digit after matching the optional `+`

```
^[+]*\d[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s./0-9]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5RGcq/1)

Or a bit more precise version::

```
^[+]?\d(?:\(\d{3}\)|[0-9]{3}) \d{3}-\d{3}$
```

Comment: I think, the OP needs to provide the pattern as string value to the `pattern` attribute. Thus one needs additional escaping for each backslash. Your stringified regex then will look like that ... `'^[+]?\\d(?:\\(\\d{3}\\)|[0-9]{3}) \\d{3}-\\d{3}$'`.